# opengl texture - no access to the image

Tags: opengl

I am trying to get a simple triangle textured, but got no image on the screen.
By using another shader that uses the colors from a color buffer it works fine. 
I checked the content of the bmp image before passing it to gl.
This is the part that loads and delivers the texture to gl

uv 0,0 / 1,0 / 0.5, 1.0

```
  bmp_s   = Load_BMP( tex_file );

  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
  glGenTextures( 1, &tex_buf->texture            );     // Create the buffer id
  glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_buf->texture );     // bind it
  glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, bmp_s->width, bmp_s->height, 0, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bmp_s->img );

  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT                   );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT                   );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR               );
  glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR );
  glGenerateMipmap( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

this is the drawing loop

```
 do
  {

    Process_Input_Events();         // get mouse & kb -- calc mvp / view matrix
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    _uid_mvp         = glGetUniformLocation( __sh_list[ 3 ].prg_id, "mvp_mx" ); 
    _uid_tex_sampler = glGetUniformLocation( __sh_list[ 3 ].prg_id, "tex_sampler" );         

    glUseProgram( sh_s->prg_id );            // use the shader

    glUniformMatrix4fv( _uid_mvp, 1, GL_FALSE, &_sys.mvp_mx[ 0 ][ 0 ] );       // send mvp

    glBindVertexArray( vao->id );            // bind vao


    glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, vao->tex_buf->texture );
    glUniform1i( _uid_tex_sampler, 0 );

    glDrawArrays( vao->prim, 0, vao->vx_b->numb );

    glBindVertexArray( 0 );                  // unbind vao
    glUseProgram( 0 );                       // unbind shader
  } while( condition );
```

and here are the shaders

```
#version 450 core

layout( location = 0 ) in vec3 vx;             // the vertex_buffer in modelspace
layout( location = 3 ) in vec2 uv_in;          // uv coordiantes for each vertex

out vec2 uv;                   

uniform mat4 mvp_mx;  


void main()
{
  gl_Position =  mvp_mx * vec4( vx, 1.0f );
  uv = uv_in;
}


#version 450 core

in  vec2 uv;                     // interpolated values from vertex shader
out vec3 out_color;

uniform sampler2D tex_sampler;       // Index of opengl texture

void main()
{
  out_color = texture( tex_sampler, uv ).rgb;
}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I am assuming you are sending data to shader is correct way. Try removing call to glGenerateMipmap.

Comment: @paritosh - yes i think so. If i use another shader without texture, everything is drawn whrer it belongs.

Comment: This doesn't proove that uv-coordinates are correct. Try outputting them as color and see if that works.

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni when we remove glGenerateMipmaps then texture completeness is violated due to the filtering mode used.

Comment: @BDL I feels generate mip map fixed functionality would be problematic if you dont have texture with size of multiples of two. So I think filtering mode could be changed to GL_NEAR if that not hot requirement

Comment: @ParitoshKulkarni: The power of two restriction has been dropped 10-15 years ago. In 4.5 (which the shaders are targeting), this is definitely not relevant.

Comment: thanks for the hints so far - got some problems with the hardware on my
dev computer. I will check everything tomorrow, and come back with the results.
merry christmas to all of you

Comment: If i use out_color = vec4( uv.x, uv.y, 1.0, 1.0 ) i see the shaded triangle.
Very good advice to use the uvs as color.
The line out_color = vec4( texture( tex_sampler,uv ).rgb, 1.0 ) delivers a blck screen. It seems the shader cannot access the texture image.
How can i verify this??

Comment: `glUsePogram()` sets `sh_s->prg_id` to be the current program, but `glGetUniformLocation()` gets the attribute number from `__sh_list[ 3 ].prg_id`. Do these represent the same program? 
Also, does any of the calls trigger an error?

Comment: @sterin - yes thats correct. sh_s is list entry 3 out of __sh_list.  I got it working, the problem was that GL_BLEND was enabled and my shaders delivered vec3 colors.